# Attempting to return a default value if converting strings to ints fails

Tags: haskell

I have a function

```
convert':: String -> Int
convert' n = read n :: Int
```

This works perfectly fine on strings that only contain integers. So when I do
`convert' "123"` it returns the int `123`.

But when I do `convert' "123s"` it throws a parse error.

I want the function to carry on returning the int where the string only contains integers, but for cases where the string contains a mix of strings and ints or only strings, I want to return `-99999`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could leverage library function [`readMaybe`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=readMaybe).

Comment: Using the readMaybe function and readMaybe function in conjunction worked for me. Thank you for the initial suggestion @jpmarinier

Comment: @pepsiMaxFan You're welcome. Note that according to SO rules, you may post an answer to your own question.

Comment: Please think very carefully whether a default like `-99999` is smart. This kind of magic number approach is usually an extremely bad idea. It makes much more sense to return a `Maybe Int`, or more often than not you shouldn't even think about “converting strings” to other types at all, but rather parse from a bigger context right to a rigid `data` structure.